# Unable to understand zabbix monitoring template

Tags: performance, shell, monitoring, zabbix

Below is the zabbix template:

`system.cpu.load[percpu,avg5].last(#1,1)}>=0.9`

I understand from the above that load average in the last five minutes is greater than 0.9. Is that correct?

I am not able to understand this part: `.last(#1,1)}>=0.9`

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Also, on zabbix GUI,  I can see constant alarm where on server I have: `load average: 6.91, 7.56, 7.54' CPU ideal time is: 85. I have a constant alarm as CPU load when I execute this template.

Is this script executed correctly?

Regards,
Tayto

Answer (score 0):

yes it's correct:

system.cpu.load[]

- percpu = total load divided by online CPU count
- avg5 = 5 minute average

last()

- #1 = the most recent value
- 1 = evaluation point moved 1 second back in time

How many CPU do you have on the host with constant alarm?

Comment: The issue got resolved. The alarm was not set to clear automatically. It had to be deleted manually. Thank you for confirming my answer.